# Combing multiple arrays in xslt

Tags: xslt, bpel

I have a requirement where there is a XML structure with a root element having 2 child element of array type  and 
Sample request structure like below

```
<Root>
  <Header>
     <Inv>12</Inv>
  </Header>
  <Detail>
     <Val>aa</Val>
     <Line>1</Line>
  </Detail>
  <Header>
     <Inv>15</Inv>
  </Header>
  <Detail>
     <Val>bb</Val>
     <Line>2</Line>
  </Detail>
</Root>
```

I have to get response like below:

```
<CreateInvoice>
  <Data>
    <Invoice>
      <Inv>12</Inv>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <Val>aa</Val>
         <Line>1</Line>
      </InvoiceLine>
    </Invoice>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <Invoice>
      <Inv>15</Inv>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <Val>bb</Val>
         <Line>2</Line>
      </InvoiceLine>
    </Invoice>
  </Data>
</CreateInvoice>
```

I tried using nested for-each on Data , but not able to get the response.
Either only inv is populating or InvoiceLine is populating.

Comment: 1. Can an invoice have more than one line?  2. Which version of XSLT does your processor support (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153)?

Comment: I am using version 1.0 and Invoice doesn't have more than 1 line.

Comment: Please correct your expected output: there is no end-tag for the Data element.

Comment: And also your input: `<Val>` does not match `</val>`.

Comment: Sorry for that , I edited the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each invoice has exactly one `Header` and one `Detail` then you can do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <CreateInvoice>
        <xsl:for-each select="Header">
            <Data>
                <Invoice>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Inv"/>
                    <InvoiceLine>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::Detail[1]/*"/>
                    </InvoiceLine>
                </Invoice>
            </Data>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </CreateInvoice>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```